# Client Object Model Equivalent of SPSiteDataQuery?

Tags: client-object-model, spsitedataquery

I'm looking for an equivalent to the SPSiteDataQuery functionality in the Client Object Model (COM).

The CamlQuery can be used with an instance of List to execute SPQuery level of aggregation, but is there an equivalent to site collection level queries for the COM?

Checked the **Web** object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web_members.aspx and also the **Site** object http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.site.aspx and don't see anything there.  **SubwebQuery** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.subwebquery.aspx had a promising name, but turns out that it's not what I'm looking for.

Perhaps there's no equivalent functionality in the COM?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Those stumbling across this in the SP2013 generation - use Search to do this, plenty available with the REST API and Result Sources.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no equivalent.

Per MSDN (suggested alternative at the end):

> The CSOM does not provide a mechanism
>   for querying data across multiple
>   lists that are not associated by a
>   lookup field. In other words, there is
>   no client-side functional equivalent
>   of the SPSiteDataQuery class. If you
>   need to perform a cross-list query
>   from client-side code, consider
>   creating a list view on the server
>   that performs the list aggregation.
>   You can then query the aggregated data
>   from your client-side code.from your client-side code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for; great information, thanks!  Now here's another question, though: a list view by nature only aggregates items in _that_ list.  The beauty of SPSiteDataQuery is that I can query _every_ list in _every_ sub-web.  So is there some new feature in 2010 lists that allows for deeper aggregation at the list level?