# JavaScript Client Object Model functionality to get all the non hidden lists of current web and listing them

Tags: 2010, list, javascript, client-object-model

We have requirement to get all the non hidden lists of current web using JavaScript Client Object Model(JSOM). I have tried the below code but failed to get the desired result.

```
function GetListDetails() {
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var user = web.get_currentUser();
    user.retrieve();
    var list = web.get_lists();
    ctx.load(web);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
            tddetails.innerHTML = user.get_loginName();
        },
        function (data) {
            alert('failed to get list. Error:' + data.get_message());
        });

    return false;
}
```

Looking for any sort of help.

Comment: you are not getting the hidden lists over here? Check if you are running the code as a administrator in that site?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [SP.ListCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410509.aspx).getEnumerator() method in order to enumerate lists, and [SP.List.hidden](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee547407.aspx) property to check, whether the list is hidden or not.

The corresponding code will look something like this:

```
function GetHiddenLists() {
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var lists = web.get_lists();
    ctx.load(lists);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
           var listEnumerator = lists.getEnumerator();
           var listInfo = '';

           while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
             var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
             listInfo += 'Title: ' + oList.get_title() + ' Hidden: ' + oList.get_hidden().toString() + '\n';
           }
           alert(listInfo);
        },
        function (sender, args) {
            alert('failed to get list. Error:' + args.get_message());
        });

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks omlin, That was really useful. Can there be any CAMLQuery stuff to get the required lists only(Non hidden)

Comment: @suryakiran unless you have more than 1000 lists in your site, the performance hit will be negligeable, so I think this approach will be ok. And anyway, there is no SPSiteDataQuery analogue for Client Object Model: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7206/client-object-model-equivalent-of-spsitedataquery