# SharePoint 2010 ClientObjectModel : Find Item by GUID

Tags: client-object-model

I have a list of 6000 listitem GUIDs. I need to check if each item still exist on the Web.

Previously, I was using the SPWeb.GetFile(GUID) method to check the item.

But now I need to convert that process usinig the ClientObjectModel. I cannot find a way to retrieve the item using the GUID.

I even tried from the "List" object. And can't find a way to retrieve the item from its GUID neither.

Please help! :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid the only way is to use CAML query. Even worse, since [you don't have a SPSiteDataQuery alternative in Client Object Model](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7206/client-object-model-equivalent-of-spsitedataquery), you can't perform cross-site queries, so you have to query each list separately.

Example code for quering a list with SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model:

```
string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";
string listTitle = "your list title here";
string guid = "put-your-guid-here";

ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
Web site = clientContext.Web;
List targetList = site.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);

CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = String.Format("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='UniqueId'/><Value Type='Guid'>{0}</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>", guid);
ListItemCollection collListItem = targetList.GetItems(query);

clientContext.Load(collListItem);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

bool itemIsFound = (collListItem.Count == 1);
```

(the code has been tested and works)

Comment: Woahhh that's nasty :P.  It will take forever to go through my 6000 items.  Anyways since I don't have the choice, I will do it that way! :)  thanks

Comment: @danbord, probably you should consider creating a custom web service which leverages the **SPWeb.GetFile** method - of course if you have a possibility (i.e. permissions) of doing this. I think this will work much faster.

Answer (score 3):

As Andrey pointed out there is no [SPList.GetItemByUniqueId Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.getitembyuniqueid(v=office.14).aspx) alternative in CSOM API.

You could utilize the following [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to load the list item by GUID in CSOM:

```
static class ListExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Load List Item by Guid 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="list"></param>
    /// <param name="itemGuid"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static ListItem LoadItemByUniqueId(this List list, Guid itemGuid)
    {
        var context = list.Context;
        var query = new CamlQuery
        {
            ViewXml = String.Format("<View><RowLimit>1</RowLimit><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='GUID'/><Value Type='Guid'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", itemGuid),
        };
        var items = list.GetItems(query);
        context.Load(items);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        return items.Count > 0 ? items[0] : null;
    }
}
```

Key points:

- `RowLimit` property is specified in query to improve performance

Comment: Please fix the ViewXml in the extension method:

- fieldname: "GUID"
- closing tag for <Eq> --> </Eq> instead of </Contains>

final ViewXml will be:
'ViewXml = String.Format("<View><RowLimit>1</RowLimit><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='GUID'/><Value Type='Guid'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", itemGuid)'