# Display all documents from multiple document libraries using client object model

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

Can anyone help me with the code to display documents from multiple document libraries using javascript client object model. I have done displaying from single document library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint doesn't provide any equivalent of SPSiteDataQuery in Client Object Model. Please see the following answer here on SharePoint StackExchange for details:

- https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/7216/1430

Thus you have to work with your document libraries separately one-by-one and then merge the results manually and then display the final list of documents. Since you already have the code for a single document library, I think you just have to call this code several times for all of your libraries.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. Your answer gave me the idea. My code is almost complete.