# CAML query on site to get all items modified after a date

Tags: sharepoint-server, caml-query, sandbox-solution, caml

I'd like to know a way or if it's possible to get all items modified from a date in a site.

Now for having this, I've got a client script because I'm in sandbox solution, I've to loop on each list of the site and then do a CAML query on each list.

The issue is I've 10000 sites so the script takes hours!

It's not efficient so the better way would be to retrieve these items in one query directly on the site, how can I do this?

I found this post but would like a solution: [Client Object Model Equivalent of SPSiteDataQuery?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7206/client-object-model-equivalent-of-spsitedataquery)

Comment: Please try to use SPSiteDataQuery, please check out the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx

Comment: Thanks for you proposition unfortunately, i'm in sandbox code so i develop a client script with context