# REST Equivalent of SPSiteDataQuery?

Tags: 2013, rest, spsitedataquery

In SharePoint 2013's server object model there is a class called `SPSiteDataQuery` that allows you to query multiple lists across a number of sub-webs in the same site collection.

**Is there an equivalent available with the REST API?**

If not, what are the alternatives with REST (or the client side object model)?

It would be helpful if you could provide examples.

Answer (score 2):

There is no  client-side equivalent class of the `SPSiteDataQuery` class. You can leverage Search APIs to get results from multiple sub sites.

See this article about [SharePoint 2013 search Query APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn423226(v=office.15).aspx)

Now for search to return new documents/items with less waiting period, you can configure **Continuous crawl** and reduce the crawl interval. The default interval of continuous crawl is 15 minutes and the lowest you can set is 1 minute.

See for more details on [Continuous crawl](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219802.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Unnie. Of course - this question is in relation to my bounty question, i.e. if I went with your suggestion of multiple sites rather than a document set how can I aggregate the data into a single data table... And the truth is I have little experience with the Search APIs, so I'm a little hesitant using this approach (although I know I should just roll my sleeves up and get stuck in!)

Comment: As a follow up then, if a change is made to a list in a sub-web, how quickly will that be reflected in a Search REST API call?

Comment: I have edited my answer. You can also explore to use OOTB content search webpart instead of writing CSOM to fetch results. You can customize the display templates to render the results in your preferred UI format

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question myself and there is no possibility to get an spsitedataquery from client object model.

What I did was writing a short webservice myself which did an spsitedataquery and queried this webservice from client side.

Reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx

And this question has already been asked:
[Client Object Model Equivalent of SPSiteDataQuery?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7206/client-object-model-equivalent-of-spsitedataquery)

Comment: Ah of course! I didn't think to create a web service. I'm going to give this a shot and get back.